# Этимология слова "тунеядство"

Tags: этимология

В связи с тем, что ведутся разговоры о возвращении закона о **тунеядстве**, бытовавшем в советское время, хотелось бы узнать о происхождении этого слова.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тунеядец - слово происходит от "туне" - "зря, напрасно" и "ядец" - едок. Т.е. "дармоед". Ниже, у Даля есть определение "тунеяда": "Тунеяды, мелкие насекомые, которые гнездятся на животных или исподволь питаются их плотью: блоха, вошь, клоп и пр."

Словарь Фасмера:

> **Ту́не**
>   нареч. "зря, напрасно", тунея́дец, ту́нный "напрасный, праздный", блр. ту́нны -- то же, др.-русск., ст.-слав. туне δωρεάν (Клоц., Супр.), болг. тун "ложный", ту́не "напрасно" (Младенов 642), словен. stúnjа ж. "бездельник", zastȯ́nj "напрасно", obstȯ́nj -- то же, вост.-слвц. tuńi, польск.-силезск. tuni "дешевый, общедоступный" (относительно польск. tani -- то же ср. Штибер, ZfslPh 9, 381), в.-луж., н.-луж. tuni.

Словарь Даля:

> **ТУНЕ** нареч. тунно сиб. втуне, даром, бесплатно, безмездно; || тщетно, дарово, напрасно, попусту, без пользы; || без вины, без причины. Туне приясте, туне дадите, Матф. Туне тебя кормить не станут. Тунно проходил, не застал никого дома. Туне о суетном печетеся. Возненавидеша мя туне, Иоан. тунный, даровой; || тщетный, напрасный; || бездельный. Тунная жизнь, пустая, суетная; дармоедная, бесполезная. Тунный выстрел, сиб. неудачный, промах, или не убивший дичи. Тунежительство, тунеядство, дармоедство или мироедство, бездельная жизнь, праздная, на чужой счет, чужетрудная. Тунеяд, -ядец, -ядка, дармоед, мироед, живущий в праздности чужими трудами, бездельник. || Тунеяды, мелкие насекомые, которые гнездятся на животных или исподволь питаются их плотью: блоха, вошь, клоп и пр. || Растенья чужеяды, которым почвою служит другое растенье, ими высасываемое, как напр. мхи, лишай, И много повойных растений жарких стран. Тунеядная жизнь, праздная, бездельная, тунеядство.